# How can I provide route to a Link component nested inside a overlay of the react-bootstrap OverlayTrigger?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, overlay, popover, react-bootstrap

React: 16.11.0
React Router: 5.1.2
React Bootstrap: 0.33.0

I am using the OverlayTrigger component from react-bootstrap which contains Link components inside of the overlay. Once I click the trigger, I am receiving the error:

```
You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> at invariant
```

How can I get router to be passed to this nested component?

I have inspected the components and can see that the OverlayTrigger is not wrapped by React Router. I have tried using Route to render the components, but it is not passing through the overlay attribute of the OverlayTrigger component.

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="bottom" overlay={overlay
} rootClose>
</OverlayTrigger>

const overlay = (
  <Popover id="cart-customize-menu" title="Select an item to customize">
    <div className="static-links">
      <Link to={`/${slug}`}>
        <i className="fa fa-calendar Mr-9"></i>
        New Meal Plan
      </Link>
    </div>
  </Popover>
)
```